# Trouble with setting numerical value against text in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a Data Validation on a cell for selecting a subject. I then have a formula that adds a number to another cell based on the text value matched. This works fine and shows the number correctly in the cell. However, I can't add up the column with the numbers in. I have tried formatting the column to 'Numbers' but it doesn't work. I assume my formula is wrong and setting the field as a text field instead of numerical?

```
=IF((OR(D5 ="Science", D5 ="Maths", )), "2", "0")
=IF((OR(D6 ="English", D5 ="French", )), "1", "0")
=IF((OR(D7 ="Geography", D5 ="History", )), "1", "0")
```

This is the formula on three different cells, which if all are matched give a column of

2
1
1

But when I then do

```
sum=(E5:E7)
```

I get 0 instead of 4

Comment: Remove the `""` around the number outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF((OR(D5 ="Science",   D5 ="Maths",   )), 2, 0)
=IF((OR(D6 ="English",   D5 ="French",  )), 1, 0)
=IF((OR(D7 ="Geography", D5 ="History", )), 1, 0)
```

or use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E5:E7)
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(E5:E7*1))
```

Comment: Thank you, shows what lack of sleep does to the brain.